# Access the Model of a page through a WebService call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an MVC 4 application. In there i have some views served. Each of these views are either for display in a browser or to be the body of an email.

Being the body of the email is the main purpose, but i have added a link to display the body in the browser.

I have a web service call that "browses" to the page and gets its source and applies it as HTML in the body of the email and then i use System.Net.Mail.

Now, in the WebService call, i need to access some values of the Model of the page being served. Is this even possible? Am i doing it in a totally wrong way? Do you have any suggestions?

Both the pages and the WebService are under the same project.

**Update** 
My actual problem is what to do with images. I want to either embed them (for email) or provide the link (for browser). So my model has the images in a \

```
list<System.IO.Stream>
```

The view renders a partial html which looks like:

```
@model MyProject.Models.ImageTag
@if (@Model.ContentType == 2)
{
    <img src="cid:@Model.ImageReference"border="0" alt="" />
}
else
{
    <img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/@Model.PropertyId/@Model.Photo" border="0" alt="" />
}
```

The web service needs to "know" the images in order to add them in LinkedResources:

```
foreach (MyProject.Models.Images image in Model.Images)
{
    LinkedResource lr = new LinkedResource(image.image, "image/jpeg");
    lr.ContentId = image.Name;
    lr.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
    lrc.Add(lr);
}
```

The above won't work of course as there is no Model. So this is my problem.

Model.Images is a

```
List<Img>
```

where img is

```
public class Img
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.IO.Stream image {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Will you use the values as part of preparing the email message or a different purpose entirely?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Kallimera...I will use the values in my webservice. What i want is access a list in the model containing images that i want to embed in the email if it is rendered as an email body. If it is to be rendered in the browser then i want to just add the links to the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I'd say you are doing it the wrong way. The view's purpose is to render the model's data to whatever representation you need: the contents of an email message, separate values formatted eg. as json or plain text, or both.

There are several options for returning different kinds of information from the same view:

- You can return a multi-part HTTP response, which is kind of tricky to handle at the client's side, but you get both types of content with the same call
- You can return the values as eg Json if an optional query parameter is present, instead of the HTML view. You would need two separate calls to return both responses.
- You can create a separate view to return the extra data
- You can return the extra data as HTTP headers

Somehow adding the data inside the HTML is not a good idea. Unless you want your recipients to receive the data as well, you would have to remove it from the returned HTML before sending the email.

I would start with the 4th option if I only wanted to return 2-3 small values that don't require complex processing, otherwise I'd create two separate views.

If the values are needed for a different scenario, ie not for preparing an email, I would definitely create a different view and a model that only returns the values I need.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But i am less than a week into MVC. So can you provide an example of the 4th option?it looks promising, as i would only need the image links.

Answer (score 0):

So your service downloads the HTML from an MVC View, and you want to put a meaningful field in that response?

You can use a few options, like:

- Send an HTTP header containing the value
- Put the value in an HTML element which you for example extract using HtmlAgilityPack
- Start the HTML with a first line containing your value, then the rest of the HTML

But it seems you want to let the HTML page to do too much. If the sole purpose of that View is to render an email body, let it do just that. Perhaps create another service method or JSON structure which gives you the values you're looking for, *and* the according URL that renders the mail template.